# Configure firefox without using the gui

Tags: command-line, configuration, firefox

in the context of automating the installation of a machine, I would like to configure firefox, specifically the proxy settings, from the command line, either by executing commands or by editing configuration files, for example.

Is this possible, and if yes how?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I would like to configure the proxy for all users.

Comment: `man firefox` should answer all your questions.

Comment: @Panki Which part of the manual talks about configuring preferences, such as proxy settings?

Comment: @Flo Probably just easier to create a new profile from scratch, then duplicate the directory. Although maybe there are UIDs that shouldn't be shared between different systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two choices (that i can think of)

1. Launch firefox, and update your profile with the correct settings (proxy ones for example). 
   Then close and retrieve your configuration in `~myusername/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxx.default/prefs.js`. *xxxxx* is a dynamic string. You can then use this user preferences for your deployement.
2. Directly update that file, after you've deployed / installed a machine, with the proxy settings.

When you will launch firefox with that user, the settings will be directly applied.

---

According to the comment of @Sparhawk, the second option would fit better. In that case we keep the original `prefs.js` as intact as possible, just changing the proxy settings:

```
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "IPADDRESS OR URL");
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 8080);
```

Comment: The reason why I didn't write up my comment as an answer is because (as I hinted) I suspect (internal) UIDs should be unique. I have tried duplicating my profile from one system to another, and had odd behaviour with things like Firefox Sync.

Comment: The second option sounds good indeed. But is there a prefs.js equivalent for all users, "global" configuration so to speak?

Comment: No, but you could also configure your proxy directly in your machine, for the whole system: in `/etc/sysconfig/proxy` for example.

Comment: @jayooin The fact that this is not possible for all users is valuable information for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to the https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig you need to create 2 files. The first file autoconfig.js should be in the install-dir/defaults/pref directory and should contain only 2 lines:

```
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

The second file firefox.cfg should be located in install-dir/ contains the settings of your proxy.

If you are using Ubuntu 22.04 or later, Firefox is provided as a snap (see https://ubuntu.com/desktop/features). You may also be using snap on other distributions. If you are unsure whether firefox is installed as snap, try the following:

```
$ which firefox
/snap/bin/firefox
or
~$ snap list
Name               Version          Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
firefox            110.0-3          2356   latest/stable/…  mozilla    -
```

Firefox snap is not able to read directories like /usr/lib/firefox and the file system of firefox snap is read-only.
Starting with Firefox 108, you have the option to put your config files in /etc/firefox (just create this directory if it does not exist). Do the following steps. You will need to adjust the IP of your proxy accordingly.

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo mkdir firefox  
$ cd /etc/firefox
```

Create the file firefox.cfg with following content (the first comment is important):

```
// IMPORTANT: Start your code on the 2nd line
pref("network.http.referer.disallowCrossSiteRelaxingDefault.top_navigation", true);
pref("network.proxy.backup.ssl", "");
pref("network.proxy.backup.ssl_port", 0);
pref("network.proxy.http", "192.168.XXX.XXX");
pref("network.proxy.http_port", XXXX);
pref("network.proxy.share_proxy_settings", true);
pref("network.proxy.ssl", "192.168.XXX.XXX");
pref("network.proxy.ssl_port", XXXX);
pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
pref("network.trr.mode", 5);
```

Create the other directories:

```
$ sudo mkdir /etc/firefox/defaults 
$ sudo mkdir /etc/firefox/defaults/pref 
$ cd /etc/firefox/defaults/pref
```

Create the file autoconfig.js with following content:

```
pref("general.config.filename", "firefox.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

Now the proxy is set for all users on this local system. You can find more infos here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1785278